# MySQL - Error 1045 (28000) for user 'jim'@'localhost' (using password YES)

Tags: mysql

I'm new to mySQL so bear with me. I'm using Windows 10, EasyPHP 13.1.

I've been reading up on MySQL, and I'm currently at the point were I'm creating a user.

I used the following code, to grant permission to the jim user

```
   GRANT ALL ON publications.* TO 'jim' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypasswd'
```

I exited out of MySQL and attempted to log in again with the password above. 
I keep getting the following error message 
"Error 1045 (28000)  for user 'jim'@'localhost' (using password YES)"
I did some research concerning the problem and ran into this:
[MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bill'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw)

I had trouble with this, so I'm not exactly sure what an anonymous user is? The responder recommends to drop the anonymous user but how does one go about doing that? I was skeptical of the other answers as they were recommending practices that are considered dangerous (Judging from the comments).

How does one go about solving this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify host information for you login.
Try below for connecting only from localhost.
GRANT ALL ON publications.* TO 'jim'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypasswd';
Or below for connecting from everywhere.
GRANT ALL ON publications.* TO 'jim'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypasswd'

Comment: Thank you, this is the right solution. Quick clarification, by "connect from everywhere", do you mean its possible to access the same database on another machine at a different location?

Comment: I think you misunderstood. From everywhere means with 'jim'@'%' login you can access your database from all hosts. But with 'jim'@'localhost' this login only from localhost. 'jim'@'10.10.10.10' with this login only from host with 10.10.10.10. ip address defined. Sorry for bad english :)

Answer (score 1):

You are probably reading the chapter 8, edition 2-3 of the book of Robin Nixon "Create dynamic websites by using: PHP, MySQL, JavaScript, CSS and HTML5".

I would advise you to find/buy English version. In the new 4th edition, the author has fixed this issue:

```
GRANT ALL ON publications.* TO 'jim'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypasswd';
```

But it's sort of bad practices since new user should be not "auto-created" with the [`GRANT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html) command. For this you have another command:

```
CREATE USER 'jeffrey'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
```